# Parse Server deploying to Heroku - Error: Cannot find module '../Adapters/PubSub/EventEmitterPubSub'

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, npm

I am migrating my Parse app to Parse Server and have it working locally. I'm now ready to deploy to Heroku but am getting an error when Heroku calls "npm start".  Heroku already has run "npm install" during the deploy process.

I get the following error:

```
parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app

node index.js

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../Adapters/PubSub/EventEmitterPubSub'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object. (/app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/LiveQuery/ParsePubSub.js:10:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-105-generic
npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! parse-server-example@1.4.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the parse-server-example@1.4.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the parse-server-example package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: did u install a module locally without making sure its in package.json for the handler during heroku install? if u check it out locally and do npm install locally to a diff root, you may find u get the same missing module err as on heroku

Comment: No everything should be in the package.json...as far as I can tell the file in question is part of the parse-server package

Comment: make sure u have recent heroku client ( that is call 'build-pack' or something for nodeJS )... does not make sense for npm install to work in local file system follow by build and then 'heroku local' and then to push to remote and have it fail... the logs on remote should show equivalent  processing.